# how to create a vector called genders in which the first 30 individuals are males and the other are females in r

Tags: r

I need to  create a vector called genders in which the first 30 individuals are males and the other are females.

I know how to create vectors obviously, but how can I code it so the first ones are males.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you include your current code?

Comment: i had no idea how do that..thats why I asked here.  I am taking a basic course (supposedly) and the instructor is no good at explaining stuff..  but the codes provided before solved this.  Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rep`. If your data is called `df` :

```
df$gender <- rep(c('male', 'female'), c(30, nrow(df) - 30))
```

If you want to create a vector and not include this in a dataframe.

```
n <- 100
gender <- rep(c('male', 'female'), c(30, n - 30))
```

Answer (score 4):

This strategy assumes you already have a dataframe and are creating another column called “genders” within that dataframe. Make them all "female" then make the first 30 "male":

```
 df$genders <- "female"
 df$genders[1:30] <- "male"
```

If you wanted a free-standing vector, then the accepted answer would be appropriate.

Sort of like what evolution does ... first make females with a full complement of sex hormones and then make males unable to produce estrogenic compounds. (The "X" chromosome is considerably shorter than the "Y" chromosome, and women use testosterone as a building block on the way to estrogens.)